# grub2 no such device (Win10 / Fedora)

Tags: fedora, boot, windows, grub2, uefi

I have Win10 installed on a nvme drive. I have installed Fedora 29 on another ssd with LVM.

When grub boots, it shows Fedora & Windows 10 on the list, as it should.

But starting with Windows leads to a black screen with

```
...commands/search.c:296:no such device: 0897-5A52
```

and fails to load, goes back to grub menu. If I start on the Windows partition from BIOS UEFI menu, Windows starts ok.

The output from `sudo blkid` shows:

```
...
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="0897-5A52" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="2a17028a-fbb0-40e8-940e-64c4d3082718"
...
```

The boot script for the Windows grub entry is:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0897-5A52
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0897-5A52
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Everything looks fine to me, and I don't get why GRUB wouldn't find the "0897-5A52" UUID, because all indicates it exists and is the right handler.

**Note**: encryption is enabled on the Windows hdd, but I guess it does not encrypt the boot partition :)

Comment: The EFI system partition filesystem might have errors and need to be checked.

Comment: How would you do that? Solved it with below though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the googlers out there.

I ended up replacing this code with a simple `set=root /dev/nvme0n1p2` and it solved the issue. [But I ran into another one, which is another matter.]

I also saw somewhere `insmod search_fs_uuid`. Maybe adding that to my code would have made it work. Didn't try though.

Working config is thus:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root=/dev/nvme0n1p2
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: But now running into: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491992/cant-boot-on-win10-with-dual-boot-fedora-29-win10-both-encrypted-partitions

Comment: Tried the same but unfortunately it did not work for me. Was that all that you changed?