# Grub "no such device: ID" unless BIOS is accessed first

Tags: dual-boot, grub, uefi, bios

The core issue is my laptop bios, that i know for sure, but infortunately, i can't change it anyway after flashing a newer version.

My Main OS is stored on my SSD
My old OS is stored on my HDD, this is where grub is also installed.

Both Options shows up correctly in grub on boot, however, one of them sometimes cannot be selected without getting the error `no such device : {8 character UUID}`.
However, if i boot into the UEFI BIOS and then to grub, then no issues.

The issue here i assume is that my SSD's case take too much time to initialize something which make it not detected reliably by the BIOS.

Which is why i tried installing grub thinking i could fix that issue since i thought it would add the neccessary amount of delay for it to be detected and be able to boot My SSD's OS from there.

Adding some timeout doesn't seem to solve the issue, i've looked at the questionnable grub doc for a couple hours now and haven't found a setting that would fix it.

any ideas on how to fix this?

i've already read about: [grub2 no such device (Win10 / Fedora)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490287/grub2-no-such-device-win10-fedora)

but i don't think it will solve my issue, and i don't want to deal with whatever other issue might occur.

Answer (score 0):

When a device is not detected immediately on power-on, but is detected after visiting the BIOS settings, it generally means that a delay would be needed between power-on and the point where the firmware detects the presence of storage devices.

Since all that happens *before* GRUB is even loaded, adding a delay to GRUB will not help here. In most distributions, GRUB will rely on the list of devices provided by the firmware (either BIOS or UEFI), unless the GRUB image is specifically built to use the hardware directly (and GRUB actually has a suitable driver in it's source code).

If your BIOS settings include a way to introduce a short delay at boot, or otherwise allow making the boot-time self-tests take just slightly longer, that might solve your issue. For example, if there is a "Fast boot" BIOS setting that is currently enabled, try disabling it.

Which disk does the 8-character UUID refer to? (See `lsblk -o +uuid`)

If it refers to the HDD, this might be a sign that the HDD is aging and you might consider replacing it pre-emptively before it actually fails.

Comment: The 8 character uuid refer to my external SSD

No my Trash tier BIOS doesn't have any options related to boot other than choosing boot order and 2 unrelated pcie settings

No i cannot flash a modded bios that would unlock the hidden advanced mode because i flashed a BIOS from acer that set the chip to read-only

Comment: Do you have fast boot on in UEFI? And with some Acer you need Control S to get more settings in UEFI.

Comment: There isn't a fast boot setting in bios, however, it is disabled in both OS installs, as for your suggestion, it does nothing, on all 4 menus